# Get the path of selected item in ListView - Win32 API

Tags: winapi, listview

I find a way to get ListView's selected item full path. I do it in treeview by using this:

```
        temp = (HTREEITEM)SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,ID_TREE,TVM_GETNEXTITEM,TVGN_PARENT,(LPARAM)temp);
```

But I don't find familiar method in listview controls.
THanks for reading this and I w8 for your answers :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690125/get-selected-item-in-listview-win32-api

Answer (score 0):

Use the [LVM_GETNEXTITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761057(VS.85).aspx) message, specifying LVNI_SELECTED as lParam, and then the [LVM_GETITEMTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761055(VS.85).aspx) message.

Comment: this method: you'll only get the logical path . But if you're in program files. How can you find the father of this folder is C:\ .