# listview combobox

Tags: c++, winapi, listview, combobox

I have added combobox to my custom listview and I am trying to set the combobox's text to the current listview subitem.

```
            case CBN_SELCHANGE:
                {
                    char txt[200];
                    ComboBox_GetText(hCombo, txt, 256);
                    int i = SendMessage(hListView, LVM_GETHOTITEM,0, 0);
                    ListView_SetItemText(hListView, i, 2, txt);
                }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean "set the listview subitem text to the selected combobox text"? Because that's what the code looks like it is doing. Also, you are passing 256 to ComboBox_GetText() but the buffer size is only 200 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listview "hot" item is the item with the cursor hovered over it and only when hot tracking and hot selection is enabled. The SDK docs for [LVM_GETHOTITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb774939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) do a poor job explaining what a hot item actually is. The [CListCtrl::GetHotItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hb54yxeb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) docs give a bit more detail.

At the time you make the selection from the combo box, the cursor is not hovered over any item in the list box so no text will be set.

You likely want to get the selected item instead:

```
int i = ListView_GetNextItem(hListView, -1, LVNI_SELECTED);
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2690125/416627) has a bit more information.